# How to change map keys into values and values into keys?

Tags: c++

I write a small program that encrypts and decrypts string. 
I generate map and to char, I add random value so I have a key to encrypt data. I have a problem with decrypting. I want to change map keys into values and values into keys and use it to decrypt but I don't know how to do it.

This is my key generator. I move the sign 13 places forward (for a test).
Ultimately, the offset value will be random.

```
std::map<char, char> generateKey(){

    std::map<char, char> map;
    char ascii = ' ', sign, newSign;
    int randomNumber = 13, overScale;

    for(int i = 0; i < 94; i++){
        if(ascii+i+randomNumber <= 126){
            sign = ascii+i;
            newSign = ascii+i+randomNumber;
            std::pair pair = std::pair(sign, newSign);
            map.insert(pair);
        } else{
            overScale = abs((ascii+i+randomNumber) - 126);
            sign = ascii+i;
            newSign = ascii+overScale-1;
            std::pair pair = std::pair(sign, newSign);
            map.insert(pair);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: 1. Create your new map `new_map`, 2. Iterate through your current map, 3. For each item in your current map, `it`, `new_map[it->second] = it->first;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::transform` to populate a new `std::map`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main() {
    // your original map:
    std::map<char, char> ma {
        {'a','b'},
        {'c','d'},
    };

    // the target map
    std::map<char, char> mb;

    // transforming using a lambda that swaps key and value
    std::transform(ma.begin(), ma.end(), std::inserter(mb, mb.begin()),
        [](const auto& pair) -> decltype(mb)::value_type {
            return {pair.second, pair.first};
        }
    );

    // printing the result
    for(auto [key, value] : mb) {
        std::cout << key << ' ' << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
b a
d c
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating your Encryption map, you can create a decryption map as well,

This example encrypts and decrypts a message using these pre-built data structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, char> encryptMap;
    std::map<char, char> decryptMap;
    char ascii = ' ', sign, newSign;
    int randomNumber = std::rand(), overScale;

    for(int i = 0; i < 94; i++){
        if(ascii+i+randomNumber <= 126){
            sign = ascii+i;
            newSign = ascii+i+randomNumber;
        } else{
            overScale = abs((ascii+i+randomNumber) - 126);
            sign = ascii+i;
            newSign = ascii+overScale-1;
        }
        encryptMap.insert(std::pair(sign, newSign));
        decryptMap.insert(std::pair(newSign, sign));
    }

    std::string message = "This is a text for ceaser cipher";
    std::string encryptedMessage;
    std::string decryptedMessage;
    for(auto const& c:message){
        encryptedMessage += encryptMap[c];
    }

    std::cout << encryptedMessage << std::endl;

    for(auto const& c:encryptedMessage){
        decryptedMessage += decryptMap[c];
    }

    std::cout << decryptedMessage;

    return 0;
}
```